# How to force equal widths on children of a flexbox container?

Tags: css, flexbox

I am using flexbox and I set the children flex-grow, flex-shrink and flex-basis properties all to 1:

```
.resident-form .flex-container {
    display: flex;
}

.resident-form .flex-container .flex-cell {
    flex-grow:1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-basis: 1;
}

.resident-form .flex-container .flex-cell:not(:first-child) {
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.resident-form .flex-container .flex-cell:not(:last-child) {
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

But the widths are not equal:
[image]

Anyway I can force that the 4 celled row to match up exactly to the 2 cell row? Meaning, 2 fields per single field in the row above.

The fields are dynamic (I could have 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 fields per row). So I can't hardcode the widths.

Comment: Setting the width of the .flex-cell to 100% and removing the grow, shrink and basis properties did the trick, but I am not sure why.

Comment: Consider posting all relevant code.

Comment: stab in the dark, because more relevant code is needed, but perhaps you should set `flex-basis: auto` on the flex-cell